# Test for an array being subset of another master array

Tags: array, typescript, set

I was trying to build a small utility function to check if an array is part of other array. It's testing if an array is a subset of another master array.

```
const masterArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const candidateArray = [2,5,6];

//Test for subset.

//create a set from the two.
const s1 = new Set(masterArray.concat(candidateArray));

//Compare the sizes of the master array and the created set
//If the sizes are same, no new elements are added that means
//the candidate is complete subset.
s1.size === masterArray.length;
```

Can this be handled in a better way?

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if `masterArray` has duplicate elements?

Comment: Good point. In my case the master array is always unique.

Comment: I can enhance it by comparing with a new set created from master array `(new Set(masterArray)).size`

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this with the type system (to check at compile time), if anyone knows how

Answer (score 1):

So the key here is that I value code that's obvious to others.

Someone else *is* likely to try to stuff duplicate elements in unless it requires a type refactor; making `const masterSet: Set<number>` and using that throughout the code is a Good Idea. That "someone else" can often be you two months down the line, too.

In this case I would not say that the point of this length comparison is obvious; it will work but it takes some thinking -- that is why it has bugs with duplicate elements. In this case I would write something  which I find more straightforward like,

```js
function isSubsetOf<x>(sub: Iterable<x>, sup: Set<x>): boolean {
  for (const x of sub) {
    if (!sup.has(x)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I am also hinting through the type system how this function works by insisting that the subset is any iterable -- so I must be iterating through it.

With a restriction to an array and a set, one can get a little swankier by using the reduce function,

```js
function isSubsetOf<x>(sub: Array<x>, sup: Set<x>): boolean {
  return sub.reduce((acc, x) => acc && sup.has(x), true);
}
```

but probably not all other readers will find that as intuitive as I do, and the former has slightly better runtime characteristics on very large lists that are obviously not subsets.